# Use the google transliterate api in python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, nlp, machine-translation

I am trying to use google transliterate [[1]](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/)   to convert hindi words written in english to hindi. e.g-
Input text- Main sahi hun.
Required text -मैं सही हूँ

I want to pass the input string to api and wants a required text in hindi language.
I am using google transliterate but as it was deprecated long time ago so can't find a suitable way to do it on python as currently the example they are providing is in javascript and not very beginner friendly. 
How to do it?

Comment: Use this library: https://pypi.org/project/google-transliteration-api/

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple python code to address what you are looking for:

```
import http.client
import json

def request(input):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('inputtools.google.com')
    conn.request('GET', '/request?text=' + input + '&itc=' + 'hi-t-i0-und' + '&num=1&cp=0&cs=1&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&app=test')
    res = conn.getresponse()
    return res

def driver(input):
    output = ''
    if ' ' in input:
        input = input.split(' ')
        for i in input:
            res = request(input = i)
            #print(res.read() )
            res = res.read()
            if i==0:
                output = str(res, encoding = 'utf-8')[14+4+len(i):-31]
            else:
                output = output + ' ' + str(res, encoding = 'utf-8')[14+4+len(i):-31]
    else:
        res = request(input = input)
        res = res.read()
        output = str(res, encoding = 'utf-8')[14+4+len(input):-31]
    print(output)

driver('mein sahi hun')
```

This will give the output as :

> में सही हूँ

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from google.transliteration import transliterate_text
result = transliterate_text('mein sahi hun', lang_code='hi')
print(result)
```